# applying ee.Filter.date() for multiple periods

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

so I am looking to import data for multiple periods (in this case, March to October for multiple years) using ee.Filter.date , but haven´t found a workable solution to to do this for more than one period. Base code looks like this:

```
var temp = ee.ImageCollection('data_source')
               .select('mean_air_temperature')
               .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-03-01', '2018-10-31'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You use calendar range to select recurring periods:

```
ee.ImageCollection(...)
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2016, 2020, 'year'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(3, 10, 'month'))
```